# Using Data from Two Matrices

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have two matrices that displays dates for each person on my team. One matrixshows the "open" dates and the other one shows the "closed" dates. I want to take the total from both matrices and combine it in a third matrix (Total report). For example:

"Open" matrix

```
         | Jan2014 | Feb2014 | Total
Jerry    | 10      | 5       | 15
```

"Closed" matrix

```
         | Jan2014 | Feb2014 | Total
Jerry    | 4       | 8       | 12
```

Total matrix (What I need to create)

```
         | Open    | Closed  | Difference
Jerry    | 15      | 12      | 3
```

I've already created the first two matrices but I am not sure how to create the total matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly but my impression is you want your total report to be a separate file which uses the totals from the other two separate reports.

It seems like the way to do this is to query your database separately in the Total Report rather than try to link it to the other two reports. You can have hyperlinks to a report inside a report but I don't think you can have cells in one report reference cells in another which seems to be what you might be getting at?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I have two separate matrices using different datasets in one report. I would like to take the total from both matrices and subtract them in the third matrix to get the difference